# how can i delete a gridview row? while the data is not yet saved in the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, delete-row

i have a system that adds items into the DataGrid, my question is how can i use the delete button? when the user wants the item deleted, user will press the button to delete the row, but i cant seem to make it work. thank you!

```
 <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridview" CssClass="table-hover" AutoGenerateColumns="true" HeaderStyle-BackColor="CornflowerBlue" BackColor="White" BorderWidth="5" BorderColor="CornflowerBlue" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gridview_SelectedIndexChanged" CellPadding="8"
     CellSpacing="0" Width="100%" OnRowDeleting="gridview_RowDeleting" EmptyDataText="No records to display">
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="CornflowerBlue"></HeaderStyle>
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" ButtonType="Button" />
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="25px" HeaderText="">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Icons/Modify.png" OnClick="Edit" />
                <%--<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" OnClick="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>--%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

here is my script

```
<script runat="server">

    void gridview_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        TableCell cell = gridview.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2];
    }
</script>
```

[grid view picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5aWH.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Gridview add `OnRowCommand="gridview_RowCommand"`

CommandField can work but I go like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="25px" HeaderText="">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="lnkDel" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Del" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID")%>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

In code behind

```
protected void gridview_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.CommandName == "Del") {
            //Get Command Argument
            int IdToDelete = Convert.ToInt32( e.CommandArgument.ToString());
            //Your Delete Command
            //Rebind GridView
        }
}
```